# jQuery show image on hover, detect some part of element ID

Tags: jquery

I want to create a image previev on link hover that is between `<a>` and `</a>` tags. Here is my code:

```
<li id="pic39">
    <span class="pr2"></span>
    <a id="pic39" href="http://shrani.slo-devs.com/index.php?p=6vxK53pk" target="_blank">Sandra</a>
    <span class="edit" onclick="location.href='index.php?e=39'"></span>
    <span class="delete" onclick="deletePIC(39)"></span>
    <i class="infoSlike">(0 ogledov | 11.03.2013 / 21:59:31)</i>
    <div id="imgPrv">
        <span id="imgPrv39">
            <img src="http://www.shrani.slo-devs.com/upl/CENSURE.jpeg" />
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want jQuery to detect the rest part of a tag id (so, number **39**) and show span that includes number **39** (span with id **imgPrv39**).

Comment: This is not an answer, but an observation: Make sure not to have the same id for more than one element, so id=pic39 is used both for the li and the a. Id's need to be unique per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li a').hover(function(){
   // You can replace the `pic` with an empty string
   var id = this.id.replace('pic', '');
   $('#imgPrv' + id).toggle();
})
```

Note that IDs must be unique, you have several elements with the same IDs, your markup is invalid, you should use classes instead.

You can also use `siblings` method:

```
$('li a').hover(function(){
   $(this).siblings('div').find('span').toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it this way. You can use relative selectors and eliminate all this ID business.

This assumes there is only one A and one SPAN in your LI. You can use class names instead if you want to be more specific.

```
$("li a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('span').show();
  },
  function () {
     $(this).find('span').hide();
  }
);
```